# Select one item at a time without DOM manipulation in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to create something like custom select. Only one item should be selected at a time. Clicked element becomes highlighted by adding corresponding css class "active". The problem is that the only way I know to remove the class from other, already selected elements is through 'querySelector' - select all items with same class and remove 'active' class from them all. And this would be a DOM manipulation, which is not a proper way to work in ReactJS, right?

What would be a right way to work around this problem?

My code so far:

````
const size = ['s', 'm', 'l']

const handleSelectSize = (value) => {
  setChosenSize(value);
}

<div className='size-variants'>{size.map(value => {
   return (
      <div className='size-item' onClick={() => handleSelectSize(value)} value={value} key={value}>{value.toUpperCase()}</div>
     )
   })}
</div>```
````

Comment: `className={'size-item ' + choseSize === value ? 'some class' : 'other class'}`

Comment: are you sure it's working ? `map` with an object ?

Comment: Right, was trying to shorten the code and made a mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood from your code that you have a state of `chosenSize` that houses the last selected `size`, so simply check each render if any `value` matches the last selected value and add the `active` class to it

```
const size = ['s', 'm', 'l']

const handleSelectSize = (value) => {
  setChosenSize(value);
}

<div className='size-variants'>{size.map(value => {
   return (
      <div className=`size-item ${chosenSize == value && 'active'}` onClick={() => handleSelectSize(value)} value={value} key={value}>{value.toUpperCase()}</div>
     )
   })}
</div>
```

Comment: `map` with an object ??

Comment: @KcH The truth is that I didn't notice that it was an object because he himself used a map, but with the object the solution is the same and you just have to use it with `Object.values()`

Comment: yeah I was just trying to bring it to notice 

Comment: You have sharp eyesight

Comment: Thank you! This worked like magic. Appreciate it!

Comment: @rey2197 I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as the correct answer and give me a score please :)

Comment: Sorry, could only mark as correct. Not enough reputation for upvoting yet. Promise to return as I earn my reputation :)

Comment: All ok mate, thanks for accepting my answer